# Adding custom fields to the article component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've recently added custom fields to the article component using the documentation in the following url:

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component

Now this adds the custom fields defined to every new and existing article. Is there a way to define custom fields for specific article layout overrides.

Example:

If I have custom layouts for the category blog, (news, portfolio, events) can I define different custom fields for each category when creating a new article?

Kind of the way custom post types work in wordpress, or the way k2 component works, can this be done in joomla alone?

Answer (score 0):

This is considerably easier to manage in K2 since the functionality is built in to do specifically what you want. It is trivial to assign extra fields to each category without having to go through the much more complex process described in your link.

However, if you want to stick with com_content, then you will need to create alternative layouts for displaying each category. You will still have all of the custom fields show up in the admin, but you can control the display on the front end with the alternative layouts. Here is the documentation (it's the same for 2.5) - http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6#Introduction_to_Alternative_Layout_Feature_in_Version_1.6

Comment: I agree Brent, it just seems like a heck of a lot of work. I've been recommended a cck plugin called [link](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/18564) FieldsAttach. The difference with this cck is it runs off the standard joomla! article and DB structure. Still I haven't yet tried this!!

Such a shame joomla dosen't integrate custom article types and custom fields within the core like wordpress 3+.

Comment: That looks like an interesting extension. I am pretty invested in K2 since it also does the same basic thing as FieldsAttach. All sites we build we completely replace com_content with K2.